# codeception rest api auth header

Tags: php, rest, yii2, codeception

How can i send auth header, when test codeception rest api?

What i have now:

1. Yii2 project
2. `"codeception/module-yii2": "^1.0.0"`
3. `"codeception/module-rest": "^1.3"`
4. Generated test class by command `codecept  generate:cest api TestName`

My class with test

```
 class CreateWorkspaceCest
 {
    public function _before(ApiTester $I)
    {

    }

    public function successCreate(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $title = 'create test';
        $description = 'test description';

        $I->sendPost('/workspace/create', [
            'title' => $title,
            'description' => $description,
        ]);

        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(\Codeception\Util\HttpCode::OK); // 200
        $I->seeResponseIsJson();

        $I->seeResponseContainsJson([
            'title' => $title,
            'description' => $description,
            'status' => 'active',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now it fails with 403 code, because backend expects header `JWT-Key: <TOKEN>`

How can i send auth header in `sendPost`
And where it is better to store auth token in one place to avoid code duplication, during writing tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeception has a method called `haveHttpHeader` you can add any header using it.

This is documented half-way down [this page](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/REST). There is also a section on authorization on [this other page](https://codeception.com/docs/10-APITesting).

There are a few built-in authorization methods, like `amBearerAuthenticated`, `amAWSAuthenticated`, but I believe that there isn't a specific method for `JWT`.

```php
 class CreateWorkspaceCest
 {
    public function _before(ApiTester $I)
    {

    }

    public function successCreate(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $title = 'create test';
        $description = 'test description';

        // You can add any header like this:
        $I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $I->haveHttpHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer user-one-access-token');

        // To add the header that you show in the question, you can use:
        $I->haveHttpHeader('JWT-Key', '<TOKEN>');

        $I->sendPost('/workspace/create', [
            'title' => $title,
            'description' => $description,
        ]);

        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(\Codeception\Util\HttpCode::OK); // 200
        $I->seeResponseIsJson();

        $I->seeResponseContainsJson([
            'title' => $title,
            'description' => $description,
            'status' => 'active',
        ]);
    }
}
```